# c++ Vectorization of overloaded operator in vector class

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization

I am trying to get a vector multiplication vectorized, but it looks like whatever you do, reason 1200 keeps it from beeing vectorized:

> Loop contains loop-carried data dependences that prevent vectorization. Different iterations of the loop interfere with each other such that vectorizing the loop would produce wrong answers, and the auto-vectorizer cannot prove to itself that there are no such data dependences.

This is (for example) the operator I would want to be vectorized:

```
class cvec3 {
...
    __forceinline void operator *=(const cvec3& v) {
        x *= v.x;
        y *= v.y;
        z *= v.z;
    }
...
}
```

I used the following test code:

```
inline void multiply_with(cvec3* __restrict arr1, const cvec3* __restrict arr2, int c)
{
    // loop vectorized
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        arr1[i].x *= arr2[i].x;
        arr1[i].y *= arr2[i].y;
        arr1[i].z *= arr2[i].z;
    }

    // loop vectorized
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        MP_VEC_WITH(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
    }

    // loop not vectorized due to reason '1200'
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        arr1[i] *= arr2[i];
    }
}
```

Is is possible to get the `*=` operator vectorized for classes? Possibly with some compiler hint I couldn't find? This is not the only place where i want vectorization. All over the place there are loops over the vector arrays and writing them all out becomes very unreadable and is a lot of work, it seems like the macro would even be better then, which also seems like a bad idea.

And a small extra question, you can see the second loop does get vectorized with the macro below. This doesn't mean much since it results in the exact same code, but why cant the compiler see that this is the same thing as the __forceinline overloaded operator?

```
#define MP_VEC_WITH(a, b) { \
    a.x *= b.x; \
    a.y *= b.y; \
    a.z *= b.z; \
}
```

Ideally I'd like something like this to be vectorized (which does get vectorized if i write the loop 3 times, once for each vector component).

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < pCount; i++) {
    vec3 tranformation = (in_velocities[i] + in_forces[i] * dt * in_invMasses[i]) * dt;
    out_pos_change[i] = tranformation;
    out_position[i] = in_positions[i] + tranformation;
}
```

---

EDIT:
I am using the Microsoft C/C++ Compiler (in Visual Studio 2015).

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015, I added it below the question.

Comment: perhaps it has to do with the aliasing? the `__restrict` attribute is lost inside the `operator*=`, I'm not sure how that works with inlining though